# Open new tab and close the previous tab python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open a new tab and close the previous tab. But it seems doesn't work! it just open the first link and throws the error: `no such window: target window already closed`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

urls = ['https://google.com','https://facebook.com','https://instagram.com']

for i in range(3):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('"+ str(urls[i]) +"');")
    driver.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After opening a new tab you need to close the current (old) tab and then to switch to the new tab.
The code below works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://facebook.com', 'https://instagram.com']

for i in range(3):
    # open a new tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + str(urls[i]) + "');")
    # close the current, old tab
    driver.close()
    # get the handle of the new, recently opened tab
    window_name = driver.window_handles[0]
    # switch to the recently opened tab
    driver.switch_to.window(window_name=window_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Selenium 4 and later versions.
Please try this code

```
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get(linkURL)
```

it will open url in new tab